# need to change the checkbox with toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

Iam using a code to display an enable disable functionality in anchor tag

```
 app_tile += '               ' + (enabled ? ('<a href="#" class="enabled"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Enabled</a>\n') : ('<a href="#" class="disabled"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Disabled</a>\n'));
```

i want to replace it with a toggle ie

```
<div class="checkbox-container">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cb1">
    <label class="checkmark" for="cb1"></label>
   </div>
```

i have used as

```
 app_tile += '               ' + (enabled ? ('<a href="#" class="enabled"><div class="slider-container"> <input type="checkbox" id="'+ app_name +'" checked> <label class="slider"  for="'+ app_name +'"></label> <div class="status"></div> </div></a>') : ('<a href="#" class="disabled"><div class="slider-container"> <input type="checkbox" id="'+ app_name +'"> <label class="thy-slider"  for="'+ app_name +'"></label> <div class="thy-status"></div> </div></a>'));
```

i have a finction call like  $(document).on('click', "a.enabled, a.disabled", changeAppStatus);

```
function changeAppStatus(e) {
        var app = $(e.target).parents('.oidapp');
        var status = $(e.target).hasClass('enabled') ? 'disable' : 'enable';
}
```

always getting class as enabled even if i toggle that into off.Not getting disable class . I need to get enable class when toggle on and disable class when it is off.
Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Perhaps you can show your code in a logical manner

Comment: var status = $(e.target).hasClass('enabled') ? 'disable' : 'enable'; i dont think this is correct in a full way it is like if($(e.target).hasClass('enabled')){ 'disable' }else{'enable'} should be if($(e.target).hasClass('enabled')){ $(e.target).addClass( 'disable') }else{$(e.target).addClass( 'enable')}

Answer (score 0):

In the logic part I have used the ^ operator, that represents XOR operations.

Remember that true or false is a single bit, if we remember XOR:

1 ^ 1 = 0
1 ^ 0 = 1
0 ^ 1 = 1
0 ^ 0 = 0

```js
//------------- Logic ------------
let enable = false //This variable has to be outside the method.

function Logic(){
  
  const square = document.getElementById("square")
  
  if(enable){
    square.classList.remove('enable')
    square.classList.add('disabled')
  } else {
    square.classList.remove('disabled')
    square.classList.add('enable')
  }
  
  enable ^= true
  
}

//------------- ToggleClass ------------
function Toggle(){
  
  const square = document.getElementById("square2")
  
  square.classList.toggle("enable");
  
}
```

```css
.square{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.disabled{
  background-color: #555;
}

.enable{
  background-color: green!important
}
```

```html
<br> With logic:
<div class="square disabled" id="square"></div>

<input type="checkbox" onclick="Logic()">

<br> With toggle class:
<div class="square disabled" id="square2"></div>

<input type="checkbox" onclick="Toggle()">
```